# How to access another project from the same solution? (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project

Let's say I'm making a game (or something similar) and the first project from the solution is level 1, and on the second is level 2, and so on... Imagine the game starts at level 1, and the player can make a choice between level 2 and 3 as to where to continue. And depending on his choice, either project 2 or 3 is run. How can I do that (if I can)? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Pro if it matters...

Comment: I will say that you a have a Design issue, levels of a game should be a collection of resources (images, sounds, animations) that are loaded and displayed inside the same solution/executable. Besides is not so clear what you mean by "access another project"

Comment: Projects are just a way for a developer to organize the source code, don't see it that way. Don't separate stuff from the player perspective. But if you really want to do that well just reference the project and use the class the same way you'd do with classes in the same project.

Comment: The game is one solution, but different levels are different projects inside of one solution. The solution is a collection of projects.

Comment: @BoyanKushlev still is not very clear what you mean by "access another project" Do you want to reuse the logic from P1 in P2 ? access some resources from P1 and P2 from the main project ?

Comment: @BoyanKushlev if I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of projects that generate executables (EXE) files? You really should have one project that creates an EXE, and other projects (levels) should generate DLLs (library projects). Your primary executable project you reference the other library projects - that way you can access the code in each of them from the single root (exe) project. I'm trying to explain this in simple terms - I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is to call "Project1.exe" from "MainProject.exe" this can help you

using System.Diagnostics;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int level ;

        //ask or determine which level wants to be played
        LaunchCommandLineApp(level);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Launch the legacy application with some options set.
    /// </summary>
    static void LaunchCommandLineApp(int level)
    {
    // For the example
    const string ex1 = "C:\\";
    const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";

    // Use ProcessStartInfo class
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.FileName = "Project" + level + ".exe";

    //I guess you dont need this
    //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    //If your project needs som parameters use this, if not removeit
    startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add Reference to Project 2 in Project 1 using VS SolutionExplorer -> Project 1 -> right click on `References` and choose `Add Reference` and then specify the dll.

Comment: You can also references the project directly.

Comment: OK, I added the reference, but now what? I see it in the "References" folder, but how do I start the project itself?

Comment: you can call your public objects for example `Project2.myPublicClass ....`

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally certain I understand your scenario, but ...

There are two options:

1. **A "Main" project references all the "level" projects.** The "Main" project is a 'shell' that contains basic game rule logic and references the level projects.  It is here that the question "which level do you want play?" will happen.
2. **Dependency Injection:** Level 1 project looks into a config file and dynamically loads the next level.